# Unable to extend react component in styled-component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to extent react component in styled-component and trying to add custom style on extended component but unable to see the style changes that I am applying

I have created a button component in `/src/newbutton.js` with following code

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

export const NewButton = ({ className, children }) => {
    return (
        <Button primary>Primary</Button>
    )
}
```

And extending and creating another button component with custom style in `/src/custom-button.js` with following code

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { NewButton } from './button'

const ButtonWrapper = styled(NewButton)`
  width: 100%;
  color: red
`;

const ExtendedButton = ({ className, children }) => {
    return (
        <ButtonWrapper />
    )
}
```

I have added the custom style like `width: 100%` & `color: red` but it is not applying on `ExtendedButton`. Infect `colour` and `width` is same as `NewButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the complete working code for future reference based on @Flat Globe solution. And it is working fine as expected.

I have modified the Button component code just by adding `className` in `/src/newbutton.js` with following code

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Button = styled.button`
  background: ${props => props.primary ? "palevioletred" : "white"};
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "white" : "palevioletred"};

  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;

export const NewButton = ({ className, children }) => {
    return (
        <Button primary className={className}>Primary</Button>
    )
}
```

I have also modified the extended-button code by just passing the `className` in `/src/custom-button.js`. check the full code below

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { NewButton } from './button'

const ButtonWrapper = styled(NewButton)`
  width: 100%;
  color: red
`;

const ExtendedButton = ({ className, children }) => {
    return (
        <ButtonWrapper className="extended-button"/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `className` to your `NewButton` in order to customize it, using `styled-components`.

Styled components works by creating a unique className that associated with a component and its CSS.

```
export const NewButton = ({ className, children }) => {
    return (
        <Button className={className} primary>Primary</Button>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can print the `className` to the console and make sure of this. `className` will contain two classes one is for the oginal `NewButton` and one for the customized `ExtendedButton`

Comment: Thanks @Flat Globe after adding `className` it is working as expected